# Get specific data out of php object

Tags: php, object, imap

Using https://github.com/ddeboer/imap, in combination with an office365 account, I need to retrieve the email address that sent the email.

To retrieve, I use:

```
$message->getFrom()
```

But the result is:

```
Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress Object
(
    [mailbox:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => my
    [hostname:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => email.com
    [name:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => Full Name
    [address:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => my@email.com
)
```

How do I retrieve only the last part in this object (I need my@email.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$message->getFrom()->getAddress()
```

[Source](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/blob/master/src/Message/EmailAddress.php).