# Read value out af an array in an PHP object

Tags: php, arrays, object

According to tis Question:
[Get specific data out of php object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166012/get-specific-data-out-of-php-object/58191284#58191284)

I have a similiar situation with:

```
print_r($message->getCc()->getAddress());
```

it geves this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAddress() on array
```

If i look at this:

```
print_r($message->getCc());
```

it seem, that the object hat an array inside:

```
Array ( [0] => Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress Object 
( 
[mailbox:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => mail 
[hostname:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => domain.de 
[name:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => 
[address:Ddeboer\Imap\Message\EmailAddress:private] => mail@spam.de )
 )
```

Whitch seems logical, for the case if there are mor then one carboncopy.

But how do i get the Array with the adress(es)?

Comment: It looks like you need `$message->getCc()[0]->getAddress()`

Comment: The print command generates `Array ( [0]` .. You cannot use these values, because they are private. Make sure the class has a method to get what you want.

Comment: Yea, thats works for the static case. But i have a loop over $message and want in every loop the array of the CC receiver.

Comment: the class ist from here: https://github.com/ddeboer/imap  Why should they are not usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
foreach ($message->getTo() as $To) {
    echo $To->getName() . " (" . $to->getAddress() . ") ";
}

foreach ($message->getCc() as $Cc) {
    echo $Cc->getName() . " (" . $to->getAddress() . ") - ";
}
```